# insert nested json object to PostgreSQL using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to insert a nested json into Postgres using pyspark. I use dataframe.

this my schema

```
 |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- params: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- entity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- input: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- format: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- maxLength: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- patterns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- prompt: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lang: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sample: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- strategy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

after creating my dataframe, whenever I try to write to postgreSQL using df.write() method I get the error

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Can't get JDBC type for struct<>

should I convert the json to string? I tried this with explode function but since its a deeply nested json it didn't help. is there a work around for this? I am new to this so any inputs would help.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out using to_json function is a work around.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, struct
df.select(to_json(struct(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns]))).alias("jsonobject")
```

if anyone has a better solution let know.

Comment: But this will create a text field - not JSON field in postgres. How can I get spark to write a JSON field?